# Probability normally random variable X is between two values

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Find δ such that $P(2 −δ < X < 2 + δ) = 0.95$ when $\mu = 2$ and $\sigma^2 = 4$

> I believe the approach to this question is to normalize the bounds of
> X. Doing so I get P(−δ/2 < Z < δ/2). Since the middle 95% of the area
> is covered, that means the lower bound is at the 2.5th percentile. I
> am not sure how to translate that to a value of δ however. Is this the
> right approach?

Comment: How many standard deviations from the mean corresponds to a two-sided probability of $0.95$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work and reasoning is correct so far.  The next thing to ask is, what is the $2.5^{\rm th}$ percentile of the standard normal distribution; i.e., what is the value of $z$ such that $\Pr[Z \le z] = 0.025$ when $Z$ is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $1$?

You can find this using a table, or a calculator, or a computer.  Note that this value of $z$ will be **negative**.  Then, using this value, you would have $\delta = -2z$ as your answer.

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry, $P(-\frac{\delta}{2} < X < \frac{\delta}{2}) = 2N_{X}(\frac{\delta}{2})-1$ where $N_{X}(x) = \operatorname{Pr}(X \leq x)$ is the CDF of $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, so the equation is reduced to $N(\frac{\delta}{2})=0.975$. It is known that the standard 95% confidence interval has critical value of $1.96$, e.g. $N(1.96) = 0.975$, hence $\delta \approx 1.96 \cdot 2 = 3.92$.